# Dynamics NAV 2015 - details group not always printed in report

Tags: report, dynamics-nav

I am working on a custom report in Dynamics NAV 2015 and am experiencing a very strange behaviour:

The report contains a table with 2 groups and one detail group.
The details group basically outputs extended texts and other information per invoice line.

Sidenote: There are more objects in the report body than just this table.

In the details group I output data from several data items that are dependants of the invoice line with some visibility condition added to avoid blank lines. (Only print when not empty)

Now the odd behaviour: 
In some scenarios (I don't know what the prerequisites are) the details group is not shown for one - seemingly random - invoice line despite the dataset containing values and no visibility condition preventing it from being displayed.

Even stranger: When increasing the size of one details row, the details disappear for a **different** invoice line while the previously missing data is printed. This is making me think it could be some report property causing this.

Did anyone ever encounter this or has an idea what may be the cause?

Comment: Don't forget that you can use CTRL+ALT+F1 on the open report to see the underlying dataset.

Comment: @ian_scho I am aware of that. Sorry for not pointing it out properly, but I did check the dataset multiple times. The data was always present in the dataset, but not printed